# Print grep Keyword if grep find a match

Tags: linux, bash, unix, scripting, grep

I have an input file `Input.txt` with the following sample keywords:

```
One 
Two
```

I also have a file `Text.txt` to search such as:

```
Bla Bla
Two more Bla
```

I want to print grep Keyword followed by a match if the grep finds a match.

The desired output:

```
Two:
========
Two more Bla
########
```

Comment: If you don't need the "header", use `grep -Ff Input.txt Text.txt`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With awk you could do something like this:

```
$ awk 'NR==FNR{a[FNR]=$0;next}{for(i in a){if($0~a[i])print a[i]":\n========\n"$0}}' input.txt test.txt 
Two:
========
Two more Bla
```

In a more readable format it would be:

```
awk 'NR == FNR { 
         a[FNR] = $0 
         next
     } 
     { 
         for(i in a) { 
             if ($0 ~ a[i]) {
                 print a[i] ":\n========\n" $0
             }
         }
     }' input.txt test.txt
```